# HTTPS Reverse proxy old tomcat application

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, reverse-proxy

I am trying to put an old Tomcat behind an Apache HTTPS reverse proxy. I configured the https virtual host to perform the actual proxying and the http virtual host to redirect everything to https:

https snippet:

```
ProxyRequests Off

ProxyPass           /old_app/       http://192.168.1.18:8080/old_app/
ProxyPassReverse    /old_app/       http://192.168.1.18:8080/old_app/
```

http snippet:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

The problem is that the website shows up, but there are no CSS or images. If inspect using Chrome Developer Console I see a lot of errors regarding mixed content, that are blocked because originally referred in http. 
I searched around and I found some suggestions regarding modifying the proxied website, but in my situation I can not modify the Tomcat webapp.
Is there a way to solve this problem? Or the only way is modify old_app source code? Maybe switching to Nginx with some particular configurations?

Answer (score 0):

**Rewrite HTML so you can change the scheme from HTTP to HTTPS**

You are looking for [mod_proxy_html](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_html.html)

The proxy itself has no way to rewrite the HTML that contains scheme, domain, or url.  This module allows you to rewrite these on the fly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I had no luck...I added

`ProxyHTMLEnable On
SetOutputFilter proxy-html
ProxyHTMLExtended On
ProxyHTMLURLMap http://example.com https://example.com`
But I still receive errors like: The page at `https://example.com/old_app/jsp/index.jsp` was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet `http://example.com/old_app/css/jquery.autocomplete.css`. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.